# Getting bathymetric slope data on ArcGIS Desktop from ASCII file?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, ascii, bathymetry

I have a project in which I have to project XYZ ASCII file data to get a DEM. It's my first maritime map, any ideas which tools should I use?

I have already tried the Spatial Analyst Tools and haven't got any results.

Comment: Which tools have you tried? Are you getting any errors?  What version of ArcGIS Desktop are you using and what licence level do you have?  Please give us a little bit more detail so we can help you.

Comment: I have Arcgis 10.3, since I am using the University computer, I don't really have an idea of the license type. 
The errors are 000735 and 050057.
Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: Please edit your question with the updated information

Comment: It sounds like you have either not specified an input file or you have specified an input folder and not specified which file type the tool needs to look at.  Please edit your question to show which tool(s) you have run and add some screenshots to show your inputs etc....